# TYPO3: How can I remove/ disable the "compatibilityX" update wizards?

Tags: upgrade, typo3-8.x

Is there a way to remove the compatibility update wizards from the upgrade wizard?

For example I upgraded from TYPO3 6 to 7 to 8 and run all update wizards except "compatibility6", "compatibility7" and "rtehtmlarea". Furthermore I have disabled the css_styled_content extension, I have migrated all my content elements and I have removed all the TypoScript which belongs to it.

BUT the system report still says update incomplete, because there are this three update wizards from above which I don't want to execute.

I know that I can ignore them, because my system is working fine without them, but I want to disable this wizards. It is possible? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I have noticed that you can just run the upgrade wizard of this too and during this you got the option to just ignore them and this will complete this tasks and you will reach the 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not remove these wizards. just ignore them

Comment: But there have to be a flag or something else, because you got this wizards not listed when you install TYPO3 8 without upgrading from a previous version. Furthermore what will happen in 10 years after different upgrade periods then you have 80% of the upgrade process done and the rest are compatibility extensions?